# Ошибка при установке Sass: While executing gem

Tags: windows-7, ruby, sass

На новом компе поставил Win7, установил Ruby, далее пытаюсь установить Sass, получаю ошибку `(ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)`. В чем проблема?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать для Ruby-целей Linux-дистрибутив какой-то?

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь это поможет: [Gem not installing, showing connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278174/gem-not-installing-showing-connection-error)